# glFinish() vs glFenceSync() + glClientWaitSync()

Tags: c++, opengl

Is there a difference between running

```
glFinish()
```

and running

```
glFenceSync(...)
glClientWaitSync(...)
```

with a big timeout?

What I'm trying to do: I run a pipeline of OpenGL commands, and I want to time how long each command takes. Without any of the above commands, everything will be pipelined / buffered, and it looks as thought the last command takes all processing time.

```
timer start

Run Opengl part 1

sync / glFinish
timer measure

Run Opengl part 2

sync / glFinish
timer measure

...
```

So I'm trying to figure out how to best measure the "speed" of the individual parts without influencing too much the overall runtime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All of the options you mentioned will influence the performance of the application, since they will stall the pipeline. The modern way of measuring timing in OpenGL is to use Timer Queries: You tell OpenGL that it should save a timestamp when the query is executed on the GPU, thus no synchronization between GPU and CPU is required. The code could look, for example, like this:

```
GLuint64 startTime, stopTime;
unsigned int queryID[2];

// generate two queries
glGenQueries(2, queryID);
...
// issue the first query
// Records the time only after all previous 
// commands have been completed
glQueryCounter(queryID[0], GL_TIMESTAMP);

// call a sequence of OpenGL commands
...
// issue the second query
// records the time when the sequence of OpenGL 
// commands has been fully executed
glQueryCounter(queryID[1], GL_TIMESTAMP);
...

// get query results
// (automatically blocks until results are available)
glGetQueryObjectui64v(queryID[0], GL_QUERY_RESULT, &startTime);
glGetQueryObjectui64v(queryID[1], GL_QUERY_RESULT, &stopTime);

printf("Time spent on the GPU: %f ms\n", (stopTime - startTime) / 1000000.0);
```

(Code taken from [Lighthouse3d.com](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/opengl-timer-query/)).

Another option is to use `glBeginQuery` with the `GL_TIME_ELAPSED` parameter, which is also described in the linked article.

Comment: Might want to at least throw a `sleep` in the loop so that it doesn't eat all of your CPU.

Comment: The spin loop waiting for availability of the result is unnecessary. Getting `GL_QUERY_RESULT` will block if the result is not available yet.

Comment: Which, usually, is undesirable. I do not think I have seen any production code that uses timer queries doing that. Any time you would want performance timing information, you want it without changing the pipeline behavior caused by stalling until the result is available. That's like accelerating 0-60 and braking back to 0 repeatedly and expecting that to represent normal driving conditions. Rolling starts, which are more representative of typical performance have vastly different results.